# Decorate half of an arrow with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-decorations

I would like to define a decoration with TikZ that only decorates half of an arrow, as in the following example:

[image: half-decorated arrow]

The above was obtained with the following "brute force" code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[decorate,
  decoration={snake,amplitude=1.5pt,segment length=8pt}]
  (0,0) to (1,0);
  \draw (1,0) to (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: If you know the length of the straight part: `\draw[decorate,
  decoration={snake,amplitude=1.5pt,segment length=8pt,post length=1cm}]
  (0,0) to (2,0);`

Comment: Thanks! this is probably good enough for my purpose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the length of the straight part, you could do:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[decorate,
  decoration={snake,amplitude=1.5pt,segment length=8pt,post length=1cm}]
  (0,0) to (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]